# Proving if $g \in \Omega (f)$ $\implies$ $g^3 \in \Omega (f^3)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I am trying to prove if $g \in \Omega (f)$ $\implies$ $g^3 \in \Omega (f^3)$ where $\forall f: N->R^+$,$\forall g: N->R^+$

I tried to set $c_4 = c_1 c_2 c_3$ since we know that $\exists c_4 \in R$,$\exists n_0 \in N$ $\forall n \in N$, $n \geq n_0$ $\implies g(n) \geq c_4 f(n)$ but I am not quite sure where to go from here, or if this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we apply the formal definition then $g(n)\in\Omega (f(n))$ means that there exists some $c_1>0$ and $n_0$ such that

$$g(n)\geq c_1 f(n)\tag{1}$$

for all $n>n_0 ~(n,n_0\in\mathbb N)$.

To show that $g(n)\in\Omega (f(n)) \implies g^3(n)\in\Omega (f^3(n))$, we need to show that
there exists some $c_2>0$ and $n_0$ such that $g^3(n)\geq c_2 f^3(n)$ for all $n>n_0 ~(n,n_0\in\mathbb N)$.

We have

$$g^3(n)\geq c_2 f^3(n)$$

so if we take the cube root of both sides then
$$g(n) \geq  \sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{2}\scriptstyle 3]{c_2}f(n)\tag{2}$$

By comparing $(1)$ with $(2)$, we can find a relationship between how we define $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: so you just let $c_2$ = $(c_1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$?

Comment: Yes, or $(c_2)^3=c_1$.